# Set Bitcoin.app to mount image before opening itself

Tags: dropbox

I have all the BitCoin data encrypted on an image on Dropbox. Is it possible to have a script that mounts the data right before I open the BitCoin.app ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No script needed. Store the app in the DMG. Keep the app (alias) in the Dock. Launching the app via the Dock will mount the DMG.

Comment: Ah smart, I didn't think of that.